# "javac: file not found: Project3.java".... Can somebody help me with this?

Tags: java, command-prompt, javac

I'm trying to run this java program from the command prompt.

However, I go to the folder that holds `Project3.java` and try to compile, but it gives me

> "javac: file not found: Project3.java."

I've already set the path to the `jdk folder`.

I tried both `"set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin"`, word for word.

I've also went to change my environment variables and changed Path, appending the above directory. Neither are working.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Comment: oh. nevermind, i was able to compile it by simply going into the src folder. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The answer was simple. I just had to compile the program from the src folder. Going into the directory wasn't enough.